# UTF8 support in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, encoding, character-encoding

When running some tests on Ubuntu I noticed that tools like gedit or the terminal create files with ascii encoding

```
$ echo 'hello world' > test.txt
$ file --mime test.txt 
test.txt: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
```

My locale is utf8 but Ubuntu does not seem to use that

```
$ locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=nl_NL.UTF-8
LC_TIME=nl_NL.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=nl_NL.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=nl_NL.UTF-8
LC_NAME=nl_NL.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=nl_NL.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=nl_NL.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=nl_NL.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=nl_NL.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

Should these files not be created with utf8? Per my settings/locale?

I don't understand with the us-ascii character encoding comes from. Is there way to tell Ubuntu/Linux to use utf8?

I did do the locale stuff for example

```
sudo locale-gen en_US en_US.UTF-8
dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

Comment: Do these files contain any non-ASCII characters?  ASCII is a subset of UTF-8.

Answer (score 3):

Plain text files have no encoding anywhere. There's no place to store meta data about how the file is encoded. When the file is created it's created according to your current locale. When you test with `file` what its type is, `file` **guesses** based on the available indicators. Since the content of the file is plain ASCII, it guesses ASCII. A file containing exclusively ASCII characters is identical in UTF-8 and ASCII (and most other encodings for that matter, they're all ASCII compatible).

Answer (score 1):

UTF-8 is a superset of ASCII. Since you're only putting ASCII characters in the file, it is both ASCII and UTF-8. `file` is reporting it as ASCII. Put characters that aren't in ASCII in there and it will report otherwise.

```
[ quentin ][ quentin@englishbreakfast ] %  echo asd > file
[ ~ ]
[ quentin ][ quentin@englishbreakfast ] %  file file
file: ASCII text
[ ~ ]
[ quentin ][ quentin@englishbreakfast ] %  echo \¨^ø> file
[ ~ ]
[ quentin ][ quentin@englishbreakfast ] %  file file
file: UTF-8 Unicode text
[ ~ ]
```

Comment: That clarifies it a bit for me. I have a file with a special character. `file --mime` comes back with `utf8`